# post json object in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i ask this question ago but don't get answer. i have a form that by filling it create json object and post to server.this form repeat in several time.
The data entry forms can be repeated several times.

```
<div ng-repeat="office in offices">
   <input type="text" ng-model="officeName">
   <input type="text" ng-model="office.employee">
   <input type="text" ng-model="office.employee">
   <button ng-click="addOffice()">Add New Office</button>
</div>
```

suppose my objects are

```
public class FormData{
   private List<Data> all;
}
public class Data{
  private String officeName;
  private List<Employee> list;
}
public class Employee{
  private String name;
}
```

how create json objects and bind data that get from form bind to this objects?
And how create form entry data?(how set ng-model)

Comment: for a form use tag `<form name="form_name">`, make sure to provide `name` attribute to be able to access it in AngularJS controller. For posting data in custom format take a look towards [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMockE2E']);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.offices = [];
  
  $scope.addOffice = function() {
    $scope.offices.push({
      employees: []
    });
  };
  
  $scope.addEmployee = function(office) {
    office.employees.push({});
  };
  
  $scope.submitOffices = function() {
    $http.post('/offices', $scope.offices)
      .success(function() {
        // Handle success.
      }).error(function() {
        // Handle error. 
      });
  };
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-mocks.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  <button ng-click="addOffice()">Add New Office</button>
  <div ng-repeat="office in offices" ng-if="offices">
    <form name="officesForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitOffices()">
      Company Name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="office.name">
      <div>
        Employees:
        <ng-form name="employeForm{{$index}}" ng-repeat="employee in office.employees">
          <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="employee.name">
          </div>
        </ng-form>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addEmployee(office)">Add Employee</button>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ offices | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

The sandboxed iframe prevents it from posting so here it is on plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2eGVa3tg3TtIhFXNpUGI?p=preview